# How do I get my eSATA drive working in Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, esata

When I connect my eSATA drive I can see it in the BIOS.
But my Windows 7 x64 seems to not detect the eSATA drive, it's not even listed in the Device Manager..

When I just connect the drive using USB 2.0 it does show it.

None of the related questions help me, I'm using a Clevo W870CU laptop.

What can I try to get my eSATA drive to show up in Windows 7 x64 too?

Comment: Some bios have an enable/disable option in the bios for secondary drives. Posting your Make and specific model of laptop may help others help you.

Comment: I did post that... No such option exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **incompatible** for an odd reason that's not worth troubleshooting...

I've used USB as an alternative for a while. But, it now seems **Windows 8 natively supports my eSATA!**

Answer (score 1):

As a question - this external SATA drive - does it have a separate AC power supply?  You mention it working with USB so it is obvious the drive works only when you hookup via eSATA it doesn't.  Does this drive attempt to obtain both power and data off the port?  They require a special powered eSATA port and your eSATA port may not be powered.

For example, the Seagate GoFlex eSATA requires such a port.

Comment: It uses a separate AC power supply.

Answer (score 0):

try and find "native sata" option in bios and turn it off

***edit:*** you could also try and prepare the partitions with some live cd that supports partitioning and see what happens then... you could do it with some kind of linux flavor that comes with a preinsalled partitioning manager (ubuntu for example)...

Comment: I'm using a laptop, such option doesn't exist. And even if it would exist it would disable my internal drives.

Comment: actually it's a common problem with laptops and sata drives - try and google "native sata problem" and see what comes up

Comment: I'll try to look for it... A Live CD won't help either. There are partitions as I already have used the drive before on USB 2.0, but I want to use eSATA from now on for speed reasons...

Comment: Do you use a Linux Live CD? If the disk doesn't show up there either, the eSATA feature is most likely disabled in the BIOS or even broken... on some desktop systems the eSATA is not available anymore if you circumvent the RAID feature - but I dn't think that apllies to your laptop.

Comment: BIOS is set to AHCI, so that should be fine. Don't have a Linux Live CD with a GUI at the moment... But I guess I'll have to wait till my planned reinstall after the exams and hope that the issue resolves itself.

Answer (score 0):

I use HP 8730w running W7 Pro x64 fully updated.

Recently I observe the following behavior.

I start Windows normally, connect an external HDD enclosure via eSATA, it is correctly detected in the system, I work with the HDD and then safely Eject it in the OS and disconnect eSATA cable from the notebook. Now if I plug the enclosure back with the same or different HDD W7 doesn't detect the drive at all. The only fix I have found so far is a system reboot.

If I start Windows in Safe Mode, then everything works fine, that is I can connect and disconnect the enclosure as many times as required without rebooting.

This suggests that W7 loads some piece of software that blocks eSATA after eject.
Is there a way to track what exactly is happening on the system level when I plug the drive?

Thank you.